# Does the JSON structure have to always be the exact same layout?

Tags: json

so here is a little example of something I'd like to know if it matters or not.

Is this the same:

```
{
 {
   "Statement" : "BankTrans1",
   "amount" : 512.46,
   "Bcode" : "EWT5620"
 }
}
```

as this:

{

```
 {
   "Bcode" : "EWT5620",
   "amount" : 512.46,
   "Statement" : "BankTrans1"

 }
}
```

Would the JSON Schema still parse the data even if its not in the same order? Apologies if this is a nooby question, just wanted to confirm.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Both structures are the same. The order does not matter here as values will be accessed by the keys.

Answer (score 0):

FROM http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf

> An object structure is represented as a pair of curly bracket tokens surrounding zero or more name/value pairs.
>   A name is a string. A single colon token follows each name, separating the name from the value. A single
>   comma token separates a value from a following name. The JSON syntax does not impose any restrictions on
>   the strings used as names, does not require that name strings be unique, and ***does not assign any
>   significance to the ordering of name/value pairs***. These are all semantic considerations that may be defined by
>   JSON processors or in specifications defining specific uses of JSON for data interchange.

Answer (score 0):

In JS try `var obj = JSON.parse(text);` and then print the `obj`, if you are getting same results for both your cases then `text` is getting parsed irrespective of the key order, else not.